# Class slots vs. initialize signature mismatch

Tags: oop, r, r-s4

Consider the following S4 class:

```
setClass('Foo', representation(model='data.frame'))

setMethod('initialize', 'Foo',
      function(.Object, a, b) {
        .Object@model <- data.frame(a, b)
        .Object
      })
```

It can be instantiated with:

```
new('Foo', a=1:4, b=4:7)
```

So far so good. However, when I try to subclass Foo I get an error.

```
setClass('Bar', contains='Foo')
>>> Error in data.frame(a, b) : argument "a" is missing, with no default
```

Personally, I would prefer to instantiate class Foo with explicit arguments because the code is more... well, explicit. However, this does not seem possible, does it? It looks like the signature of `initialize` must match the slots that the class has, otherwise it's a problem waiting to happen. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement is that `new` called with no arguments, `new("Foo")`, must work. Also, it's probably better practice for your initialize method to take `...`, to `callNextMethod`, and to have arguments *after* the `...` (because `initialize` is documented to use unnamed arguments for initializing contained classes). So

```
setMethod(initialize, "Foo", function(.Object, ..., a=integer(), b=integer()) {
    callNextMethod(.Object, ..., model=data.frame(a, b))
})
```

Normally one wants to insulate the user from calling new, and will instead use a constructor `Foo`. Typically the constructor does whatever coercion you might have instead put in the initialize method, so the initialize method is just not specified.

```
Foo <- function(a=integer(), b=integer(), ...) {
    model <- data.frame(a, b)
    new("Foo", model=model, ...)
}
```